# a simple Vue.js addition app

Tags: vue.js

Im very new to Vue.js.  I’m trying to build a simple app that totals a list of items. But it also, should have the option to ‘disable’ the individual items so that their value would *not* contribute to the total.  (UPDATE: the button should toggle the disabled state)

Visually, the disabled items would simply be greyed-out, (i dont want their amounts showing zero)

I was imagining perhaps, targeting the parent item with a disabled attribute (when the btn is clicked). And then….a check would be made for the existence of this attribute, when the totalling is done (and any item without the attribute (class?) would be skipped)

But I have no idea how this would work in Vue World.  Anyone willing to help out please?  Or even point me in the right direction?

HTML

```
<div id="app">
    <div id="item1">{{ item1.amt }} <button type="button">exclude me</button></div>
    <div id="item2">{{ item2.amt }} <button type="button">exclude me</button></div>
    <div id="item3">{{ item3.amt }} <button type="button">exclude me</button></div>

    <br>

    <div id="total">total: {{ item1.amt + item2.amt + item3.amt }}</div>

</div>
```

JS

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: "#app", 
    data: {
        item1: {
            amt: 10
        },
        item2: {
            amt: 20
        },
        item3: {
            amt: 30
        }
    }
});
```

https://codepen.io/dagford/pen/oyKXYP?editors=1010

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the vuetiful world of Vue.

If you need the to see the working code, go [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zagvNe)

But let me explain you what I actually did

JS

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: "#app", 
    data: {
        items:[
        {
            id:'item1',
            included:'true',
            amt: 10
        },
        {
            id:'item2',
            included:'true',
            amt: 20
        },
        {
            id:'item3',
            included:'true',
            amt: 30
        }
        ]
    },
    computed:{
        itemTotal(){
            return this.items.reduce(function(sum, item){
                if(item.included){
                    return  item.amt + sum;
                }

                return sum;
            },0)
        }
    }
});
```

It is very crucial to model your data in a correct way. As your items where having common properties, so it could come in an array. I have include the id and a flag know whether it is included or not.

I also have added a method to compute the total every time item changes.

Template:

```
<div id="app">    
    <div v-for="item in items"
         :id="item.id"
         :key="item.id">
        <span>{{item.amt}}</span>
        <button @click="item.included = false"> exclude me</button>

    </div>
    <br>
    <div id="total">total: {{ itemTotal }}</div>
    </div>
```

In template code I have added v-for to render the whole list, and at button click I am just changing the flag (included). Computation of the itemTotal is triggered automatically and smartly by vue. An at last I am rendering the itemTotal in separate div.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Ankit, thanks a lot for this. How though could the code be modified so that the button toggles the 'included' state.   (Sorry, I should have mentioned that in the description)

Comment: Ankit - I've got the toggle working now! thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

if you want to  button toggles the 'included' state and exclude the value

try it use `v-on:click` and a `unclick boolean varible`

simple demo looks like:

---

```js
var app = new Vue({
    el: "#app", 
    data: {
        item1: {
            amt: 10,
            unclick:true
        },
        item2: {
            amt: 30,
            unclick:true
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <div id="item1">{{ item1.amt }} 
        <button v-on:click="item1.unclick = !item1.unclick" type="button">
         {{ (item1.unclick?'exclude me':'include me')  }}
        </button>  
    </div>
    <div id="item2">{{ item2.amt }} 
        <button v-on:click="item2.unclick = !item2.unclick" type="button">
         {{ (item2.unclick?'exclude me':'include me')  }}
        </button>  
    </div>
    <br>
    <div id="total">total: {{ 
            (item1.unclick?item1.amt:0) 
            + (item2.unclick?item2.amt:0)
        }}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for this IT.  How would this work with multiple items though?  Your total is not looping over the items i dont think?

Comment: thanks agin @IT WeiHan!  It still, though...requires the total to be manually added (unless Im mistaken).   Its not flexible to allow for the adding/removing of items.  Eventually this will be a dynamic database driven list, so it needs to be closer to Ankit's solution (which uses a loop).